# Web scraping tool to scrape a dynamic page based on current day

Tags: html, scraping

I need to scrape a theatre webpage to know whether the bookings for next week has been opened. I am planning to write a scraper if the page has the required HTML element for the next Friday based on the current date.

For example, if the current date is June 4-9, I should scrape the page
https://www.spicinemas.in/chennai/show-times/10-06-2016?seats=2

Basically the date in URL will be the next Friday as it is the releasing date.

For specific movies, I like to store the name and its releasing date in DB so that it will take special cases for them.

Which tool would be optimal and take least time? I need to write this for several Movieplex websites and each one has different mechanism to check if the booking has been opened.

Is [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) suitable for this? Please suggest.

Comment: Does the tool must be written in Java or Python, or are other programming languages fine, too?

Comment: Fine if there is any other languages. Other than Java, i have to learn and implement. I don't think language will be the main barrier here in implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If the page is straight html, (not flash or query based), you should be able to do this very quickly and simply by using the [python](https://www.python.org/)'s [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) libraries.

The best bit is that you can rapidly test it out using python or [iPython](http://ipython.org/) interactivly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Steve's answer here, you can check out Python's [lxml library](http://lxml.de/) which is a bare-bones scraping library in Python.

As libraries like [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) and Beautiful Soup are written as wrappers over lxml, it is faster than them and most Python-based scrapers.